# How to uninstall the Service links module?

Tags: installation

I had a hard time with the [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) module (version 7.x-2.1) in Drupal 7. All the harder that links showed for some articles and not others. So while testing and trying to figure out how to configure, it took some time before I realized there were some issues in it.

Anyway, icons are poors, and I replaced it by the [Easy Social](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_social) module, which is quite fine for me and such a pleasure to configure as it is so easy and *understandable*.

The issue I have now is to remove the [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) module: I could disable it, and it remains listed as part of the modules (actually there is quite a bunch of modules in [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links)). But then when I go to the *uninstall* tab, it does not show up.

I tried the module widgets on top of [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) to see if I could better configure the display of the links, but it didn't help. And I can't remove it either. My install is quite new and clean.

Any suggestions about how to uninstall the [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) module?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, Service Links 7.x-2.1 does not create tables of its own and the uninstall hook only deletes some configuration variables.

If you can't see the module in the uninstall tabs then you have probably deleted the module's folder before uninstalling. If this is the case, you can restore the module's folder and then uninstall the module (no need to enable it again).

Or you can run `DELETE FROM variable WHERE name LIKE 'service_links_%'` to your database.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't delete any folder, and I just checked : folders are still there. Also I ran `SELECT * FROM  variable WHERE name LIKE 'service_links_%'` but there is nothing. Mystery remains...